# Exportar dados para excel usando html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber como se faz para usar uma biblioteca javascript chamada [ExcelJS](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) no navegador

Estou importando assim no html

```
<html>

    <body>

        <script src="exceljs.js"></script>
        <script src="meu.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Essa biblioteca eu baixei [daqui](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.1.1/exceljs.js), está nesta [lista](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/exceljs)

Estou usando a seguinte função no arquivo `meu.js`

```
      $(()=>{
           exportarParaExcel()
       })
const exportarParaExcel= async () => {
        const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");

        worksheet.columns = [
        {header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10},
        {header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32}, 
        {header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'dob', width: 15,}
        ];

        worksheet.addRow({id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1)});
        worksheet.addRow({id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1965, 1, 7)});

        // save under export.xlsx
        await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx');

        //load a copy of export.xlsx
        const newWorkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        await newWorkbook.xlsx.readFile('export.xlsx');

        const newworksheet = newWorkbook.getWorksheet('My Sheet');
        newworksheet.columns = [
        {header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10},
        {header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32}, 
        {header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'dob', width: 15,}
        ];
        await newworksheet.addRow({id: 3, name: 'New Guy', dob: new Date(2000, 1, 1)});

        await newWorkbook.xlsx.writeFile('export2.xlsx');

        console.log("File is written")
    }
```

Mas neste caso ele dá o seguinte erro:
**Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Excel is not defined**

Quando declaro usando

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
```

Dá o erro:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Como faço para usar essa bibliteca no navegador?

Comment: Creio que pode usar o https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Comment: Deu isso aqui `Uncaught Error: Module name "exceljs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Provavelmente é algo errado no load, faltam arquivos ou afins, veja se assim resolve: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="exceljs.js"></script>`

Comment: Mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu não sei se estou fazendo confusão, faça isso só pra testar: `var Excel = require(['exceljs']);`

Comment: Agora deu isso aqui `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {`